# PHP update MySQL Database First, then Send data to MailChimp

Tags: php, mysql, mailchimp

I'm using the "Embedded Forms" option from MailChimp to send new subscriber info to my MailChimp Subscriber list. What I'm trying to do is also send this data to my MySQL database for my website.

The form MailChimp provided is this:

```
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
    <form action="http://my_example_site.com/subscribe/post?u=[my_api_key]&amp;id=[my_list_id]" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
        <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
            <h2>Subscribe to our mailing list</h2>
                <div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
                <div class="mc-field-group">
                    <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address  <span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
                    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
                </div>
                <div class="mc-field-group">
                    <label for="mce-FNAME">First Name </label>
                    <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="" id="mce-FNAME">
                </div>
                <div class="mc-field-group">
                    <label for="mce-LNAME">Last Name </label>
                    <input type="text" value="" name="LNAME" class="" id="mce-LNAME">
                </div>
                <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
                    <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
                    <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
                </div>
                <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="[my_api_key]" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
                <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I want to not only send this data to MailChimp but also INSERT this new data into my MySQL database for the website.

I was originally thinking something like this:

- Change the form action to:  `action = "updateList.php"`. This file will be my insert data into MySQL. Then somehow forward the data to MailChimp??

updateList.php:

```
<?php
     require "config.php"; /* MySQL database connection details */

     if (isset($_POST['EMAIL'])) { $email = $_POST['EMAIL']; }
     if (isset($_POST['FNAME'])) { $fname = $_POST['FNAME']; }
     if (isset($_POST['LNAME'])) { $lname = $_POST['LNAME']; }

     if (strlen($email)>0 && strlen($fname)>0 && strlen($lname)>0) {
         $date_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 

        $result = "INSERT INTO subscribers (EMAIL, FNAME, LNAME, DATE_TIME) VALUES (:email, :fname, :lname, :date_time)";
        $statement = $db->prepare($result);

           $statement->bindValue(":email", $email);
           $statement->bindValue(":fname", $fname);
           $statement->bindValue(":lname", $lname); 
           $statement->bindValue(":date_time", $date_time); 

           $stmt = $statement->execute();   

          /****** INSERT CODE TO FORWARD THE DATA TO MAILCHIMP??  *******/

     }
```